# Can i work in the same time with JSF 2.2 and Restful?

Tags: java, rest, servlets, jsf-2, restful-architecture

I'm already working with JSF 2.2 and java beans and EJB3 (CDI and not seam framwork).
I learned how to use JaxRS Restful and i want to khnow If I can improve my projects by using this technology with my JSF pages?
JSF works only with one servlet and to use restful I have to add another servlet in the web.xml file?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can add as many Servlets as you want to your JavaEE web project.

You could either add another servlet to the web.xml file, or use annotations. I suggest you check out the Oracle JavaEE tutorials for examples.